# How to send email alerts to child object records

Tags: email-alert

here's my hectic situation in Salesforce. I have a custom child object 'B' (having master-detail relation with parent object A which is a standard object) will be having few records in child object(depends on situation the record count may be up to 10 and more) and they will send each record for approval soon after getting approval or rejection to all (child) records we have to send email alert (which contains few fields info in the records) to all child records at a time. How can we achieve this, Thanks in Advance guys.

Comment: This sounds like it should be doable with approval processes, email alerts, workflow rules, and roll-up summary fields. Did you have any specific issues getting this set up?

Comment: Hi Martin Thank you for reply, Approval process is working fine. Thing is how to collect all child records(roll up), I should go for a trigger?. And how can I send email alert?.

Comment: If you have a master-detail relationship, there is a field type called "roll-up summary" that you could use. As for email alerts, you could drive that off a workflow rule on parent object since you want all child records approved before sending the email.

Comment: Create 2 Email Templates one for approval and one for rejection then Create Approval Process and set them accordingly.